# how to read class name passed to class annotation from the annotation

Tags: java, junit, java-annotations

I have created my own annotation and this annotation receives `class.class`. The class itself is extending another class.

I am trying to achieve almost the same as using `@RunWith()`, but instead of running the class I would like to use it to get the `class.class` in my parent class, so I will not need to send it in a `@Before` annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface RunWithClass {
  /** @return the classes to be run */
  Class<?>[] value();
}

@RunWithClass(UnitTests.class)
public class UnitTests extends TestProxy {

and the method within TestProxy 

private void updateClassReference() {
/**
here I would like to get the class in the above case will be  UnitTests
(so I will be able to create an instance of the class for reflection
**/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the value of @RunWithClass annotation and use it as below:

```
Class<?>[] classesToRun = this.getClass().getAnnotation(RunWithClass.class).value();
```

I can try to give a better answer if you clarify your question.

Comment: You can thank me by accepting the answer, if it solves your problem.